# Using animation and thread

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I would like to create an animation.
Why do I get this error?

> 01-16 12:09:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
>
> 01-16 12:09:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(895):
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException 01-16 12:09:33.388:
> E/AndroidRuntime(895):    at
> com.example.pages.Comments.initialImageViewSms(Comments.java:38) 01-16
> 12:09:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments.access$0(Comments.java:36) 01-16
> 12:09:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments$1.run(Comments.java:24) 01-16 12:09:33.388:
> E/AndroidRuntime(895):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
> 01-16 12:09:45.587: E/AndroidRuntime(906): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
> 01-16 12:09:45.587: E/AndroidRuntime(906):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 01-16 12:09:45.587:
> E/AndroidRuntime(906):    at
> com.example.pages.Comments.initialImageViewSms(Comments.java:38) 01-16
> 12:09:45.587: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments.access$0(Comments.java:36) 01-16
> 12:09:45.587: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments$1.run(Comments.java:24) 01-16 12:09:45.587:
> E/AndroidRuntime(906):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
> 01-16 12:15:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(990): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
> 01-16 12:15:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(990):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 01-16 12:15:11.178:
> E/AndroidRuntime(990):    at
> com.example.pages.Comments.initialImageViewSms(Comments.java:37) 01-16
> 12:15:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments.access$0(Comments.java:35) 01-16
> 12:15:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at
> com.example.pages.Comments$1.run(Comments.java:23) 01-16 12:15:11.178:
> E/AndroidRuntime(990):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

BaseFragment:

```
package com.example.pages;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

}
```

Comments:

```
package com.example.pages;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Comments extends BaseFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            initialImageViewSms();
        }
    }).start();
    
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments,container,false);
    return view;
}

private void initialImageViewSms(){
    
    ImageView imageview_sendsms = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_send_sms);
    imageview_sendsms.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.send_sms_anim);
    AnimationDrawable animdrawable = (AnimationDrawable)imageview_sendsms.getBackground();
    animdrawable.start();
}
}
```

send_sms_anim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false"
>

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/send_sms_one"
android:duration="100"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/send_sms_two"
android:duration="100"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: check this [http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/] for your Problem, may be this solve your problem

Comment: why do you start your animation from a thread?

Answer (score 0):

you can't update your `UI` in new Thread, `UI` must be update in `UI` thread

you try update UI in `initialImageViewSms();` that is not in UI Thread

you can use **runOnUiThread** , **Handler** or **AsyncTask** class to run in `UI` thread or move out you method from thread because i don't see any other code in that.

Comment: what you want? you want start Animation for your `ImageView`?

Comment: OK, see my Edit and use one of them.